# Did IE10 change the definition of window.location.port?

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-10

I noticed some JavaScript code that inspects `window.location.port` was breaking in IE10 Platform Preview 10.0.1008.16421 today.

For instance, in IE10, go to http://www.microsoft.com. Open up the developer tools and type in `window.location.port` and it returns `80`. What happened? Why does IE10 suddenly return the integer `80` when all other IE browsers return the `""` (empty string) on the same site? IE10 also returns `80` in all of the downlevel modes.

Compare the result for IE8/9 on http://www.microsoft.com : `window.location.port` is `""`!

Any idea if this is a new behavior for IE10, a logged bug in the platform release, or a has-yet-to-be-reported bug?

Comment: I'd say the buggy behavior is in < IE10. There's always a port number associated with a request. I'm guessing MS didn't see fit to report '80' as it is the default port.

Comment: Chrome reports `window.location.port` as being `''` =/

Comment: I imagine that there is a "default port assumed", so it would only be `''` if not 80/443, etc, in those other browsers. The real question: is *is* this property well-defined and, if so, where?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/Overview.html#url-decomposition-idl-attributes which makes it sound like it should be `'80`' *if and only if* the URI included a port, which happened to be 80 such as `http://www.microsofto.com:80`.

Comment: So that makes it seem as though it IS buggy behavior in IE10 - both for being an integer and returning a value without one specified in the URI.

Comment: @pst - You should add that as an answer. It appears to be correct, and therefore an IE10 bug if it returns a value when no port is present in the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *sounds* like a bug, although I do not known of any such reported issue:

The [HTML5: 2.6.2 Parsing URLs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/Overview.html#parse-a-url) states that "[the port] is the substring matched by the  production, *if any*."

Furthermore, the [HTML5: 2.6.6 Interfaces for URL manipulation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/Overview.html#url-decomposition-idl-attributes) section gives an example input of `http://example.com/carrot#question%3f` which specifies that the port should be `""` - an (empty string).

**UPDATE**

This is a real bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/817343/ie11-scripting-value-of-htmlanchorelement-host-differs-between-script-created-link-and-link-from-document